# Phoenix - Group detail items in a Template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Given the following:

```
[
  {"2016-05-06T08:59:50", "Woke up"},
  {"2016-05-06T09:30:20", "Ate breakfast"},
  {"2016-05-07T01:48:10", "Went to bed"}
]
```

I'd like to display the (above) detail lines in a web page, but grouped by day:

```
<h1>6 May 2016</h1>
8:59 - Woke up
9:30 - Ate breakfast

<h1>7 May 2016</h1>
1:48 - Went to bed
```

In Phoenix, what's the best way to do this using a Template? Is it best to transform the results from my Ecto query to a parent/child data structure in the Controller before rendering in the template? If so, would I then use a nested loop in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the dates by using [Enum.group_by/3](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#group_by/3):

```
Enum.group_by(dates, fn {date, _} -> Ecto.Date.cast!(date) end)
```

Which results in the following:

```
%{#Ecto.Date<2016-05-06> => [{"2016-05-06T09:30:20", "Ate breakfast"},
  {"2016-05-06T08:59:50", "Woke up"}],
  #Ecto.Date<2016-05-07> => [{"2016-05-07T01:48:10", "Went to bed"}]}
```

However, maps are not an ordered data type, so you should probably sort them after using [Enum.sort/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Enum.html#sort/1):

```
Enum.group_by(dates, fn {date, _} -> Ecto.Date.cast!(date) end) |> Enum.sort()

[{#Ecto.Date<2016-05-06>,
  [{"2016-05-06T09:30:20", "Ate breakfast"},
   {"2016-05-06T08:59:50", "Woke up"}]},
 {#Ecto.Date<2016-05-07>, [{"2016-05-07T01:48:10", "Went to bed"}]}]
```

Your templates should look something like:

```
<%= for {date, events} <- @dates do %>
  <h1><%= date %></h1>
  <%= for event <- Enum.reverse(events) do %>
    <%= event %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note that we reverse the list here, this is because `group_by` will build the list by prepending the head to the list.

Comment: Great answer. I would also add that the best place to put this code is neither template nor controller, but view.

Comment: Could you elaborate. I thought the purpose of the controller was to translate data?